Create lines in QGIS from a list of coordinates in Excel
I need to create lines in QGIS (currently using 3.40.0. version) from a list of coordinates in an Excel file.
The Excel list has the following fields: ID, X_start, Y_start, X_end, Y_end
I would like to create one line per each ID.
I was looking for something simmilar to "Create points layer from table" but instead of points, I need to create lines from table.
I read about "points to path" but I find it dificult and ther might be another easy way.

You need to use the Geometry by expression processing tool.
First load your Excel table in QGIS then use the tool with the folowing expression :
MAKE_Line(Make_point("X_start", "Y_start" ), Make_point("X_end", "Y_end"))


